# hasOwnProperty always returns false using Typescript

Tags: javascript, resolver, typegraphql

I'm implementing a filter in TypeGraphQL and I'm first checking to see if the Class has the property requested by the user to filter. I'm trying to use hasOwnProperty but it always returns false even though the property is correct.

Query within Resolver:

```
@Query(() => [Dog] )
  async dogs(
    @Arg('filter') filter: FilterInput
  ): Promise<Dog []> {
    console.log(filter.field)
    console.log(Dog.prototype.hasOwnProperty(filter.field))

    const dogs = await Dog.find({where: {[filter.field]: `${filter.value}`}})

    return dogs
  }
```

Dog Entity:

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Dog extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Field()
  @Column()
  name: string

  @Field()
  info(@Root() parent: Dog): string {
    return `gender: ${parent.gender} ; name: ${parent.name}`
  }

  @Field()
  @Column()
  gender: string
}
```

FilterInput Type:

```
import { InputType, Field } from "type-graphql";


@InputType()
export class FilterInput {
  @Field()
  field: string

  @Field()
  value: string
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the `filter.field in Dog.prototype` syntax?

Comment: I have tried doing  ' Dog.prototype[filter.field] ' but it throws an error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Dog'.

Comment: Yes, that is because you are using TS with `strict` config set to `true`. But that is a good practice. Try to make something like this:
`if(filter.field in Dog.prototypre) {...}`
Inside this if scope, TS will know that `filter.field` is of type `keyof typeof Dog.prototype`

Comment: I just tried `if(filter.field in Dog.prototype) {   console.log(true) }   else {   console.log(false)   }`  and it still always returns false no matter if the field is a valid field

Comment: Whats is the `filter.field` value anyway? It must be a string

Comment: Just edited the question to include the FilterInput type. And yes, it is a string that gets sent from the clientside as an argument

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209593/discussion-between-pedro-mutter-and-jeffrey-penner).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with an enum and just compare the input string with the enum values
enum:

```
export enum dogFields {
  name = 'name',
  gender = 'gender'
}
```